# Funcao mail no php

Tags: php, email

Estou usando a função *mail* do php e gostaria de verificar se os emails foram enviados com sucesso, mas não sei como o posso fazer. Como eu poderia verificar se o e-mail foi enviado com sucesso?

Comment: Para saber ao certo você terá que ter acesso ao relatório do EXIM por exemplo ou de qualquer outro relatório de um software similar, levando-se em conta que seu servidor seja LINUX. Se você possuir uma hospedagem que te dê acesso via VHM/CPanel eu fiz uma classe que te dá o resultado de forma amigável. Ela fornece todas as informações de envio de acordo com o ID da mensagem, ou seja, se ela foi enviada, rejeitada ou se está na fila de entrega. https://github.com/mjpsolucoes/VHMAuth

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você perguntou se tem como saber se foi enviado, tem, e, aconselho a realizar a 3ª opção:

1 - Você pode utilizar `error_get_last()`, enquanto `mail()` retornar falso.

Com `print_r(error_get_last())`  você começa algo como isto:

```
[type] => 2 [message] => mail(): Failed to connect to mailserver at "x.x.x.x" port 25, verify your "SMTP" and "smtp_port" setting in php.ini or use ini_set() [file] => C:\www\X\X.php [line] => 2
```

2 - Você poderia fazer

```
if (!mail(...)) {
   // lol!
}
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php

```
É importante notar que só porque o email foi true, não significa que o e-mail vai realmente chegar ao destino pretendido.
```

Se você precisa suprimir avisos, você pode usar:

```
if (!@mail(...))
```

3 - No fim das contas, aconselho a você utilizar disparo de e-mails através da classe PHPMailer(). Há uma centena de tutorias sobre isto. A única dificuldade que você terá, será em configurar a clase com as portas e o servidor SMTP de sua hospedagem. Exemplo de uma função:

```
    <?php

    require_once("smtp/class.phpmailer.php"); //link do arquivo abaixo

       define('GUSER', 'meuemail@meu.dominio.net');   // <-- Insira aqui o seu GMail
       define('GPWD', 'minhasenha');      // <-- Insira aqui a senha do seu GMail


       function smtpmailer($para, $de, $de_nome, $assunto, $corpo) { 
       global $error;
       $mail = new PHPMailer();
       $mail->IsSMTP();     // Ativar SMTP
       $mail->SMTPDebug = 0;      // Debugar: 1 = erros e mensagens, 2 = mensagens apenas
       $mail->SMTPAuth = true;    // Autenticação ativada
       $mail->SMTPSecure = 'TLS'; // SSL REQUERIDO pelo GMail
       $mail->Host = 'smtp.do.meuservidor.net';  // SMTP utilizado
       $mail->Port = 587;      // A porta 587 deverá estar aberta em seu servidor
       $mail->Username = GUSER;
       $mail->Password = GPWD;
       $mail->SetFrom($de, $de_nome);
       $mail->Subject = $assunto;
       $mail->Body = $corpo;
       $mail->AddAddress($para);
       $mail->IsHTML(true);
       if(!$mail->Send()) {  //olha aqui o que você queria
          $error = 'Mail error: '.$mail->ErrorInfo; 
          return false;
       } else {

          $error = 'Mensagem enviada!';      
          return true;
       }
    }
          //Insira abaixo o email que irá receber a mensagem, o email que irá enviar (o mesmo da variável GUSER), 
          //Email que recebe a mensagem, email que envia a mensagem, o Assunto da mensagem e por último a variável com o corpo do email.

          if (smtpmailer($emaildestinatario, $emailremetente , $nomeremetente, $assunto , $corpodamensagem)) {


    }
          if (!empty($error)) echo $error;
?>
```

https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/class.phpmailer.php

Answer (score 2):

Não é porque a função `mail()` retornou `true` e o email saiu do teu servidor e chegou até o servidor do destinatário que significa que será entregue. Até entendo não se tem como verificar se o e-mail realmente chegou com sucesso ao *destinatário*, pois a função de e-mail é apenas um "comando", quem faz o trabalho na verdade é um *serviço de comunicação* (*serviço de SMTP*) que existe no seu servidor.

Quando você usa `mail(...);`, ele envia o comando para o "serviço" e este serviço só retorna a resposta para o PHP que ele recebeu a sua instrução.

O e-mail fica em uma fila e isto pode levar bastante tempo para envia-lo (variando conforme o servidor), pois podem haver vários emails na fila de de uma mesmo servidor e por este motivo não tem como saber se foi feito a comunicação do SMTP com o destinatário, se não a sua página PHP poderia ficar travada por vários minutos.

Portanto em [tempo de execução](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tempo_de_execu%C3%A7%C3%A3o) não tem como saber se o e-mail foi para o destinatário, a única resposta que você vai ter é se o SMTP recebeu as suas instruções ou não.

## Alternativa

> Nota: Mais detalhes http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bounce_message#Bouncing_vs._rejecting

Geralmente quando enviamos um e-mail e ocorre uma falha o SMTP envia um *email* para a Inbox (caixa de entrada) do próprio destinatário, neste e-mail contem detalhes do erro, esse log de erro não tem formato padrão, cada *serviço de SMTP* possui um formato, infelizmente, portanto usar estes dados é algo difícil, mas ainda sim você pode usa-los (que eu saiba não existe nada pronto para usar isto).

Leia um exemplo desta situação no [serverfault](https://serverfault.com/questions/594898/mail-delivery-failed-for-a-message-i-didnt-send)

Comment: Boa tarde @TesterApo resta alguma duvida? Se não, por favor escolha a resposta que mais lhe agradar e marque como "correta". Grato.