# Dados de formulário não enviam para o email

Tags: php, envio-de-email

Fiz um pequeno formulário para envio de e-mail. Mas, quando realizo o teste de envio não chega nada no e-mail de destino. Como não tenho muita experiência nesta parte não consegui identificar o erro, já que quando envio não dá nenhum. Segue meu HTML:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="pt-br">
<head>
<? include "includes/head.php"?>
</head>
<body>
<div id="site">
<div class="container">
    <section class="contato">
        <? include "includes/topo.php"?>
        <div class="envolve">
            <h2>CONTATO</h2>
            <div>
                <p>Preencha o formulário</p>
                <form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="mail.php">
                    <input type="text" name="nome" placeholder="Nome:" required>
                    <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="E-mail:" required>
                    <input type="tel" name="telefone" placeholder="Telefone:" required>
                    <input type="text" name="estado" placeholder="Estado:" required>
                    <textarea name="mensagem" placeholder="Mensagem:"></textarea>
                    <input type="submit" name="enviar" value="Enviar">
                </form>
            </div>          
            <div>
                <p>Av. Sumare, 1642 - Sumare - SP</p>
                <p><strong>Contratação de artistas</strong></p> 
                <p>(11) 2977-5177</p>
                <span class="fr">
                <iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m14!1m8!1m3!1d3657.666898030628!2d-46.676697399999995!3d-23.544480200000002!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x94ce578cc9a3c755%3A0xe7e810c950cee00b!2sAv.+Sumar%C3%A9%2C+1642+-+Sumar%C3%A9%2C+S%C3%A3o+Paulo+-+SP%2C+01252-120!5e0!3m2!1spt-BR!2sbr!4v1423246864426" width="412" height="298" frameborder="0" style="border:0"></iframe>
                </span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
</div> 
<? include "includes/rodape.php"?>    
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Meu código PHP:

```
$para     = "andre@twinshark.com.br";
$assunto  = "Contato pelo site";
$nome     = $_POST['nome'];
$email    = $_POST['email'];
$telefone = $_POST['telefone'];
$estado   = $_POST['estado'];
$mensagem = $_POST['mensagem'];

$corpo  = "<strong>Mensagem de contato<br><br></strong>";
$corpo .= "<strong>Nome:</strong>$nome";
$corpo .= "<br><strong>E-mail:</strong>$email";
$corpo .= "<br><strong>Telefone:</strong>$telefone";
$corpo .= "<br><strong>Estado:</strong>$estado";
$corpo .= "<br><strong>Mensagem:</strong>$mensagem";

$header .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset= utf-8\n";
$header = "From: $email Reply-to: $email\n";    

@mail($para,$assunto,$corpo,$header);

header("location:contato.php?msg=enviado");
```

Comment: Olhe na caixa de SPAM do destinatário, pois você está utilizando função mail. Tudo é possível.

Comment: Recomendo a minha resposta, para envio de email por SMTP:

http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/45556/funcao-mail-no-php/45568#45568

Comment: `mail` retorna `true` ou `false`. Então use isto ao seu favor. Porém como é dito na minha resposta http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/45558/3635 não é possível verificar se o e-mail chegou ao destinatário, apenas se chegou ao serviço do servidor de e-mail. Porém como disse o @QMechanic73 pode estar ocorrendo algum erro no seu código que você ocultou.

Comment: Lollipop isso foi a primeira coisa que eu fiz olhei em todas caixas de email, quanto ao link que vc passou do phpmailer, eles serve para todos servidores? Por exemplo o servidor que eu estou testando é da locaweb.

QMechanic ja tinha feito o teste sem o @ não tem erros tb

Comment: se meu código está correto, será que o problema é então a configuração do servidor?

Comment: Guilherme como eu já havia dito ao QMechanic não dá nenhum erro quando eu tiro o @ simplemente escreve enviado na url mas não envia nenhum email

Comment: Espera aí, você disse que os dados do formulário não vão para o email, isso quer dizer que vc recebe o email, mas ele vem sem os dados preenchidos? Ou você nem chega a receber o email? E por favor vc fez o teste do TRUE e FALSE que eu falei?

Comment: @Guilherme Nascimento, os dados dão como enviado na url mas nada chega ao email, quanto aquele teste de tirar o @, eu já fiz isso e não dá nenhum erro nenhum

Comment: Aparece como enviado por que você adicionou um redirecionamento. Você deve usar TRUE/FALSE com IF algo como: if(mail()) { header(); } else { echo 'erro'; }, se mesmo assim a página redireciona, então o seu problema não é com o PHP e sim com antispam ou algo do gênero.

Comment: verifique as normas de envio de email do seu provedor de hospedagem.. a maioria não permite o envio direto sem autenticação ou por meio de configuraçoes específicas. Então consulte a documentação e suporte do seu provedor de hospedagem.

Comment: @user4451 vai no phpmailer. Com ele você configura uma conta de email para envio e não fica dependente de cada servidor onde vai rodar seu app.

Answer (score 2):

Você fez:

```
// A variável $header não existia mas, se sua conf do PHP permitir, ela será criada
// e nenhum erro será lançado, caso contrário o servidor retornará um erro 500
$header .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset= utf-8\n";

// Aqui você está usando dois cabeçalhos diferentes na mesma linha, o que é inválido
// From: $email
// Reply-to: $email
// E a atribuição anterior é apagada
$header = "From: $email Reply-to: $email\n";
```

Recomendo alterar o fim do código para:

```
$headers = array(
    "Content-Type: text/html; charset= utf-8",
    "From: $email",
    "Reply-to: $email"
);

$retorno = @mail($para, $assunto, $corpo, implode("\r\n", $headers));

if($retorno) $msg = "enviado";
else $msg = "nao_enviado";

header("location:contato.php?msg=$msg");

?>
```

No seu arquivo `contato.php` você deve tratar a variável `$_GET["msg"]` para cada valor possível, e exibir a mensagem adequada ao usuário.

Comment: fiz como vc disse e troquei o código pelo que você sugeriu e continua da mesma forma. Quanto a tratar variável, como eu havia dito no início do post meu conhecimento não é tão grande em php e eu não sei tratar variável.

Answer (score 2):

A função `mail()` retorna false caso não envie, utilize um if para verificar se foi enviado com sucesso.

**Exemplo:**

```
if(mail($para,$assunto,$corpo,$header)){
    // enviado com sucesso. faça algo
}else{
    echo "Não foi possivel enviar o email.";
}
```

Bom isso é o básico, agora você tem que analisar como esta o seu servidor, e verificar no seu `php.ini` os seguintes parâmetros:

```
[mail function]
; For Win32 only.
; http://php.net/smtp
SMTP = localhost
; http://php.net/smtp-port
smtp_port = 25

; For Win32 only.
; http://php.net/sendmail-from
;sendmail_from = me@example.com

; For Unix only.  You may supply arguments as well (default: "sendmail -t -i").
; http://php.net/sendmail-path
;sendmail_path =

; Force the addition of the specified parameters to be passed as extra parameters
; to the sendmail binary. These parameters will always replace the value of
; the 5th parameter to mail().
;mail.force_extra_parameters =

; Add X-PHP-Originating-Script: that will include uid of the script followed by the filename
mail.add_x_header = On

; The path to a log file that will log all mail() calls. Log entries include
; the full path of the script, line number, To address and headers.
;mail.log =
; Log mail to syslog (Event Log on Windows).
;mail.log = syslog
```

Primeiro verifique qual é a porta que você esta tentando enviar, quando eu tento enviar para o gmail a porta que utilizo é a 465 com ssl

Já passei diversos problemas com essa função e no final acabei escolhendo uma library chamada phpmailer. ela facilita bastante o envio e o debug.

[Topicos sobre ela no StackOverflow](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?q=phpmailer)

[Exemplo de envio](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/89690/envio-de-email-via-phpmailer-para-gmail)