# Envio de email via PHPmailer para Gmail

Tags: php, html, phpmailer, gmail

Não consigo de jeito nenhum enviar um email para a minha conta Gmail via PHP. Tinha um projeto anterior onde tentei usar o `phpmailer` e não o consigo pô-lo  a funcionar corretamente (2 meses tentando). Agora terminei um site e falta apenas colocá-lo no ar, e o `phpmailer` não funciona.

Segue o meu código  HTML:

```
<form class="coluna coluna-3" method="POST" action="email.php">
    Nome:<br/>
    <input type="text" name="nome" maxlength="50"/><br/>
    e-mail:<br/>
    <input type="text" name="email" maxlength="50"/><br/>
    Assunto:<br/>
    <input type="text" name="assunto" maxlength="50"/><br/>
    Mensagem:<br/>
    <textarea name="mensagem" rows="10" cols="50" maxlength="500"></textarea>
    <br/>
    <input type="submit" value="Enviar"/>
</form>
```

E este é o código do meu arquivo `email.php`:

```
// Inclui o arquivo class.phpmailer.php localizado na pasta phpmailer
require_once('../phpmailer/class.phpmailer.php');//já tentei sem ../ também
// Inicia a classe PHPMailer
$mail = new PHPMailer();
// Define os dados do servidor e tipo de conexão
// =-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=
$mail->IsSMTP(true); // Define que a mensagem será SMTP
$mail->Host = "smtp.gmail.com"; // Endereço do servidor SMTP
$mail->Port = 587;
$mail->SMTPAuth = true; // Usa autenticação SMTP? (opcional)
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';
$mail->Username = 'eu@gmail.com'; // Usuário do servidor SMTP
$mail->Password = 'minhasenha'; // Senha do servidor SMTP
// Define o remetente
// =-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=
$mail->From = "eu@gmail.com"; // Seu e-mail
$mail->FromName = "Joãozinho"; // Seu nome
// Define os destinatário(s)
// =-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=
$mail->AddAddress('eu@gmail.com', 'Fulano da Silva');
// Define os dados técnicos da Mensagem
// =-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=
$mail->IsHTML(true); // Define que o e-mail será enviado como HTML
// Define a mensagem (Texto e Assunto)
// =-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=
$mail->Subject  = "Mensagem Teste"; // Assunto da mensagem
$mail->Body = "Este é o corpo da mensagem de teste, em <b>HTML</b>!  :)";
$mail->AltBody = "Este é o corpo da mensagem de teste, em Texto Plano! \r\n :)";
// Define os anexos (opcional)
// =-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=
//$mail->AddAttachment("c:/temp/documento.pdf", "novo_nome.pdf");  // Insere um anexo
// Envia o e-mail
$enviado = $mail->Send();
// Limpa os destinatários e os anexos
$mail->ClearAllRecipients();
$mail->ClearAttachments();
// Exibe uma mensagem de resultado
if ($enviado) {
  echo "E-mail enviado com sucesso!";
}
else {
  echo "Não foi possível enviar o e-mail.";
  echo "<b>Informações do erro:</b> " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
}
```

É desnecessário adicionar o código CSS porque não ajudará em nada.

Eu estou a enviar um email para mim mesmo porque estou apenas testando se funciona. Quando funcionar, coloco os textos pelo `$_POST` como deve ser.

Estou em `localhost`, uso **ubuntu-MATE 15.04**, meu servidor é o **Apache2**. O site está em `/var/www/meuprojeto/` dentro da pasta **meuprojeto**, está uma pasta `phpmailer` com dois arquivos baixados do GitHub - "`class.phpmailer.php`" e "`class.smtp.php`"
(segui este tutorial: [Enviar emails pelo PHP usando phpmailer](http://blog.thiagobelem.net/enviar-e-mails-pelo-php-usando-o-phpmailer/)).

Para descobrir informações do Gmail, olhei em: [Envie emails via PHP e SMTP utilizando o GMail ou o Google Apps](http://www.gn10.com.br/blog/dicas/envie-emails-php-smtp-gmail-google-apps/) .

Qualquer informação adicional necessária, é só pedir.

Comment: Poderia detalhar o erro que recebes?

Comment: Erro: 2015-10-01 02:59:23 SMTP ERROR: Failed to connect to server: (0) 2015-10-01 02:59:23 SMTP connect() failed. github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting Não foi possível enviar o e-mail.Informações do erro: SMTP connect() failed. github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting

Comment: Versão do php: PHP 5.6.4-4ubuntu6.2 (cli) (built: Jul  2 2015 15:29:28) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2014 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.6.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2014 Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.0.4-dev, Copyright (c) 1999-2014, by Zend Technologies

Comment: A porta que o Gmail usa para SSL é a `465`. A 587 é para TLS

Comment: Uma dica para "diminuir" a segurança do Gmail é mexer aqui: https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps Você "diminui" a segurança da autenticação do Gmail pra conseguir liberar o serviço! Embora eu estou tentando e ainda não consegui fazer funcionar!
Por isso é importante criar um e-mail exclusivo para essa tarefa por exemplo:
naoresponder@seudominio.com.br
ou
marketing@seudominio.com.br
ou alguma coisa do gênero!

Comment: A minha solução foi um mix de duas respostas ai:
1- No Google configurações habilitar envio por Apps menos seguros;
2- Usar SSl com essa porta 465;
3- Não tive que liberar porta alguma, creio que já estava liberada.

Comment: **NOTA:** os posts em geral que falam de "aplicativos menos seguros" estão desatualizados. Faz um bom tempo que o PHPMailer [suporta autenticação XOAUTH2](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Using-Gmail-with-XOAUTH2), que permite usar o google mail normalmente sem precisar baixar a segurança, via token de aplicativo.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sem qualquer informação do erro é bem difícil tratar o problema. Suponhamos que estás utilizando a versão 5 do [PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer).

Inclua no seu arquivo a chamada do *autoload* :

```
require('phpmailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php');
```

Ative o debug:

```
// 1 = Erros e mensagens
// 2 = Apenas mensagens
$mail->SMTPDebug  = 1;
```

Verifique se as credenciais estão corretas;

Comment: Segui tua sugestão com valor 1 e me apareceu a seguinte mensagem:

2015-10-01 02:59:23 SMTP ERROR: Failed to connect to server: (0) 2015-10-01 02:59:23 SMTP connect() failed. https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting Não foi possível enviar o e-mail.Informações do erro: SMTP connect() failed. https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting

Comment: Tem certeza que as credenciais estão corretas? Você está fazendo isso em localhost?

Comment: Como vejo as credenciais? Estou fazendo em localhost. Funcionou pro email do Terra, mas o Gmail não ta indo.

Comment: As credenciais são os dados **email** e **senha** que você utiliza.

Comment: então estão corretos. Eu acabei optando por utilizar a função mail() do php, o site está no ar e o e-mail ta funcionando numa boa. Será que é algum problema de porta que o PHPmailer não ta indo quando está online? (em localhost foi pro servidor terra, mas no servidor não)

Comment: Eu tive um problema recentemente com um servidor, onde ele não fazia qualquer conexão SMTP nele, mas no localhost eu conseguia com o mesmo script. Verifique com sua hospedagem, abra um ticket e peça suporte técnico. Encha o saco, eles bloqueiam mesmo.

Comment: Pow, Marcelo, você falou um negócio que faz muito sentido pra mim, porque foi a equipe do servidor mesmo que disse "não usa PHPmailer não, usa a função mail() nativa mesmo". Perco muito em deixar de usar o PHPmailer?

Comment: Não exatamente, @EnriqueRené, vai depender muito do que você precisa. [Nesta questão do SOen](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1268150/1432957) Há uma resposta para o uso da função mail() nativa e o PHPMailer.

Answer (score 2):

Precisa entrar na conta do Gmail e

> **[habilitar envio por Apps menos seguros]**

senão não vai enviar.

Além disso, altere :

```
De: $mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';

Para: $mail->SMTPSecure = '**tls**';
```

Agora vai enviar.

Answer (score 0):

No `require_once` coloque só o `/phpmailer/class.phpmailer.php`. Como está na raiz do projeto, pode ser que funcione, ou só `phpmailer/class.phpmailer.php`.

Comment: Usei a sugestão do Marcelo de Andrade, não tinha funcionado. Depois (deixando a sugestão dele) segui a tua sugestão e coloquei só "phpmailer/class.phpmailer.php" e então apareceu a mensagem de erro (que vou comentar na resposta dele). Tua dica deu certo, obrigado por tentar ajudar e obrigado por resolver em parte também.

Answer (score 0):

Apenas para complementar esse post, existe uma outra solução para enviar e-mail para o gmail a partir do backend php. Foi a única solução que funcionou para mim.

Basta baixar, utilizar o [SwiftMailer](http://swiftmailer.org/) e o código abaixo. Além disso, é necessário alterar uma configuração no Gmail para permitir o acesso de dispositivos menos seguros (google my account -> sign-in & security -> Conected apps & sites -> Allow less secure apps: ON). Devido a essa configuração, acredito que não é uma solução definitiva para enviar e-mails para o Gmail, mas como no meu caso só estou utilizando para fazer uns testes, não há problema.

Post original com essa solução:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/712392/send-email-using-the-gmail-smtp-server-from-a-php-page

```
<?php
require_once 'swift/lib/swift_required.php';

$transport = Swift_SmtpTransport::newInstance('smtp.gmail.com', 465, "ssl")
  ->setUsername('GMAIL_USERNAME')
  ->setPassword('GMAIL_PASSWORD');

$mailer = Swift_Mailer::newInstance($transport);

$message = Swift_Message::newInstance('Test Subject')
  ->setFrom(array('abc@example.com' => 'ABC'))
  ->setTo(array('xyz@test.com'))
  ->setBody('This is a test mail.');

$result = $mailer->send($message);
?>
```