# Enviar e-mail através da classe PHPMailer

Tags: php, formulário, phpmailer

Tenho o seguinte `form` na minha página `index.php` :

```
<form id="form-contato" method="post" action="email.php">
    <div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="6u 12u(mobile)">
                <input type="text" name="name" id="nome" placeholder="Nome" />
            </div>
            <div class="6u 12u(mobile)">
                <input type="text" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Email" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="12u">
                <input type="text" name="subject" id="assunto" placeholder="Assunto" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="12u">
                <textarea name="message" id="mensagem" placeholder="Mensagem"></textarea>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row 200%">
            <div class="12u">
                <ul class="actions">
                    <li><input type="submit" value="Enviar mensagem"/></li>
                    <li><input type="reset" value="Limpar campos" class="alt" /></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Criei uma página email.php para enviar os dados preenchidos no form da index.php:

```
    <?php

require_once("phpmailer.php");
error_reporting(E_ALL);
error_reporting(E_STRICT);
date_default_timezone_set('America/Sao_Paulo');
$ip = getenv("REMOTE_ADDR");
// variáveis que guardam os dados vindo do form
$nome = utf8_decode($_POST['nome']);
$email = utf8_decode($_POST['email']);
$assunto = utf8_decode($_POST['assunto']);
$mensagem = utf8_decode($_POST['mensagem']);

$Email = new PHPMailer();
$Email->SetLanguage("br");
$Email->IsMail();
$Email->IsHTML(true);

$Email->From = $email;
$Email->FromName = $nome;
$Email->AddAddress("raphaelpradoo@hotmail.com");
$Email->Subject = $assunto;
$Email->AddBcc($email);

if(!$Email->Send()) {
    echo "Erro: " . $Email->ErrorInfo;
} else {
    echo "Mensagem enviada!";
}
```

Porém o e-mail não está sendo enviado. O que está faltando ?

Comment: O que aparece de erro?

Comment: Mailer Error: Could not instantiate mail function @MarceloBonifazio

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Dificuldades no Envio de E-mail usando PHP](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/67012/dificuldades-no-envio-de-e-mail-usando-php) ou [Envio de email via PHPmailer para Gmail](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/89690/envio-de-email-via-phpmailer-para-gmail)

Answer (score 0):

Tente usar essa configuração...
No meu esta funcionando...
OBS: Está configurado para gmail

```
<?php
require_once '../PHPMailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php';

  $mail = new PHPMailer;
  $mail->isSMTP();
  $mail->CharSet = "utf8";
  //$mail->SMTPDebug = 3;
  $mail->Host ='smtp.gmail.com';
  $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
  $mail->Username = 'seuemail@gmail.com';
  $mail->Password = 'suasenha';
  $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls'; //ssl
  $mail->Port = 587; //465
  $mail->FromName = "De";
  $mail->isHTML(true);
  $mail->AddReplyTo("Emailcasoforresponder", "Nome");
  $mail->addAddress('email@gmail.com', 'nomeDestinario'); //E-mail destinario
  $mail->Subject = "Assunto";
  $mail->Body = "Mensagem";

  if(!$mail->Send()){       
    return 'Erro ao enviar e-mail: '.$mail->ErrorInfo;
  }else{
    return TRUE;
  }
```

Comment: No phpmailer q eu baixei não veio essa classe PHPMailerAutoload

Comment: @RaphaelPradodeOliveira eu baixei a ultima versão... Depois de baixar descompacte dentro do seu projeto e faça a inclusão do arquivo PHPMailerAutoload.php  Segue o link: https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer