# Formulario de contato com PHP

Tags: php, html

Olá, eu criei um formulario em html, mas não esta funcional , por que tenho pouco conhecimento em PHP, como posso desenvolver o script para enviar o email para meu hotmail?

Este é meu formulario

```html
      <main>
              <section class="contato">    
                    <div class="container">
                        <form>
                            <div class="cols">
                                <div class="col">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <input type="text" placeholder="Nome" required>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <input type="email" placeholder="Email" required>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <input type="number" placeholder="Telefone">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <select>
                                            <option>Selecione uma opção</option>
                                            <option>Orçamento</option>
                                            <option>Duvidas Referente ao Serviço</option>
                                            <option>Outro</option>
                                        </select>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="text-area">
                                <textarea placeholder="Escreva sua mensagem"></textarea>
                            </div>
                         
                            <div class"form-group">
                                <button class="botao medio"><i class="fa fa-envelope" aria-hidden="true"></i> Enviar</button>
                            <div>
                 
                            
                            
                        </form>
                    </div>
              </section>
         </main>
```

Comment: Pode usar a biblioteca  [PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer) ou a função nativa [mail()](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.mail.php) do PHP. Mas tente [edit] sua pergunta e dar mais detalhes, por exemplo o que não está funcional, algum erro, algum aviso, seu código. Uma pergunta mais concreta.

Comment: @UzumakiArtanis    Desculpe,na verdade eu tenho apenas o formularo em html, ainda não escrevi o codigo em php,por isso preciso da ajuda de como fazer o script

Comment: Por favor, coloque o código aqui, especifique a sua pergunta. O que você tem pronto? Mostra pra gente! :)

Comment: Acabei de Editar a pergunta

Comment: Pesquise um pouco sobre o assunto, até nos links que postei antes ou no google mesmo, então desenvolva alguma coisa e volte com uma dúvida mais concreta (um erro talvez).

Comment: Tem várias perguntas aqui mesmo no SO https://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?q=Enviar+email+%5Bphp%5D  Recomendo esse aqui https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/23602/como-enviar-e-mail-com-php e esse também https://wiki.locaweb.com.br/pt-br/Envio_autenticado_na_revenda

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Envio de email via PHPmailer para Gmail](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/89690/envio-de-email-via-phpmailer-para-gmail)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primeiramente você deve configurar o formulário para que ele possa enviar os dados para algum lugar:

```
<form action="algumapagina.php" method="post"> //Action é a pagina para qual o formulario vai enviar e methos como ele vai enviar os dados
```

Agora definir o nome das propriedades para poder pegar os seus respectivos valores:

```
<input name="nome" type="text" placeholder="Nome" required>

<input name="email" type="email" placeholder="Email" required>

<input name="numero" type="number" placeholder="Telefone">

<select name="tipo"></select>

<textarea name="mensagem" placeholder="Escreva sua mensagem"></textarea>
```

Depois de fazer isso, você tem que pegar estes valores na página do qual você enviou o usuario:

```
if(isset($_POST)){ //Checa se os dados foram enviados
    $nome = $_POST['nome'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $numero = $_POST['numero'];
    $tipo = $_POST['tipo'];
    $mensagem = $_POST['mensagem'];
}
```

Definir o corpo do email:

```
$conteudo = "$nome\n$email\n$numero\n$tipo\n$mensagem";
```

E enviar o email normalmente:

```
mail($destinatario, $assunto, nl2br($conteudo), "From: joaolegal@gmail.com");
//Onde a variavel $assunto contem o assunto do email, $destinatario, pra quem o email será enviado e From, a partir de que email ele virá
```

#### Não se esqueça de configurar o `php.ini`!

Veja [isso](https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_mail_mail.asp), se se tiver mais duvidas. Ou a [documentação oficial](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.mail.php).

Comment: essa ultima linha
`mail($destinatario, $assunto, nl2br($conteudo), "From: joaolegal@gmail.com");`
Eu para mim colocar por exemplo: $Meu-nome ?
E para que server e como configuro o php.ini ?