# mysql_query() expects parameter 1 to be string, resource give

Tags: php

Então vasculhei o meu código pra achar uma solução, porém o erro pode ser de banco de dados, toda vez que finalizo o cadastro era pra ser enviado um email, porém da esse erro.

> Warning: mysql_query() expects parameter 1 to be string, resource
>   given in C:\xampp\htdocs\Controla\cadastrando.php on line 67 Erro no
>   envio do e-mail: SMTP connect() failed.
>   https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting

```
<?php    
    $email = $_POST['email'];

    $result_leados = "INSERT INTO tb_usuarios email VALUES ('$email')";
    $resultado_leados = mysql_query($con, $result_leados);

    //Inicio Enviar e-mail
    require 'PHPMailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php';

    $Mailer = new PHPMailer();

    //Define que será usado SMTP
    $Mailer->IsSMTP();

    //Enviar e-mail em HTML
    $Mailer->isHTML(true);

    //Aceitar carasteres especiais
    $Mailer->Charset = 'UTF-8';

    //Configurações
    $Mailer->SMTPAuth = true;
    $Mailer->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';

    //nome do servidor
    $Mailer->Host = 'localhost';
    //Porta de saida de e-mail 
    $Mailer->Port = 465;

    //Dados do e-mail de saida - autenticação
    $Mailer->Username = 'controla.estoque2018@gmail.com';
    $Mailer->Password = 'modercontrol';

    //E-mail remetente (deve ser o mesmo de quem fez a autenticação)
    $Mailer->From = 'controla.estoque2018@gmail.com';

    //Nome do Remetente
    $Mailer->FromName = 'Controla estoque';

    //Assunto da mensagem
    $Mailer->Subject = 'Titulo - Confirmação de email';

    //Corpo da Mensagem
    $mensagem = "Olá <br><br>";
    $mensagem .= "Confirme seu e-mail acessar o sistema, após isso execute o login. <br> <br>";
    $mensagem .= "Sua Conta Foi Desbloquueada</a><br> <br>";
    $mensagem .= "Se você recebeu este e-mail por engano, simplesmente o exclua.<br> <br>";
    $mensagem .= "Controla estoque";

    $Mailer->Body = $mensagem;

    //Corpo da mensagem em texto
    $Mailer->AltBody = 'conteudo do E-mail em texto';

    //Destinatario 
    $Mailer->AddAddress($email);

    if($Mailer->Send()){
        echo "E-mail enviado com sucesso";
    }else{
        echo "Erro no envio do e-mail: " . $Mailer->ErrorInfo;
    }

    //Fim Enviar e-mail
?>
```

Comment: Atenção: concatenar query como string corre o risco de ataque de SQL Injection. https://www.tecmundo.com.br/tecmundo-explica/113195-sql-injection-saiba-tudo-ataque-simples-devastador.htm

Comment: O primeiro erro é que a query deveria ser o primeiro parâmetro.

Comment: Coloquei a query como primeiro parâmetro, porém o erro do SMTP connect(), continua

Comment: Erro no envio do e-mail: SMTP connect() failed. https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting

Answer (score 1):

O comando SQL está errado, o nome dos campos no `insert` deve vir entre parênteses, assim:

```
 $result_leados = "INSERT INTO tb_usuarios(email) VALUES ('$email')";
```

Além disso, não é possível enviar email através do **gmail** usando o `Host` como "localhost". O correto seria:

```
$mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';
```

Por fim, veja se sua conta do **gmail** está configurada para enviar email através de Sites/Apps.
Logue na conta do **google** e visite esse link para ver se está habilitado: https://myaccount.google.com/lesssecureapps

Por último, se ainda estiver com problemas pode ser algo mais específico. Aqui tem uma outra discussão com algumas boas respostas: [Envio de email via PHPmailer para Gmail](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/89690/envio-de-email-via-phpmailer-para-gmail)

Comment: Continua o mesmo erro